Cant load Udp4Dxe.efi in UEFI Shell when starting OVMF firmware using QEMU
I want to use UEFI's network functionality to test my UNDI driver, but error  "Failed to locate EFI_RNG_PROTOCOL: Not Found" occured when loading Udp4Dxe.EFI in UEFI Shell using “load Udp4Dxe.EFI” command
FSOpen: Open '\net\Udp4Dxe.efi' Success FSOpen: Open '\net\Udp4Dxe.efi' Success [Security] 3rd party image[0] can be loaded after EndOfDxe: 
PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x1)/Ata(Primary,Master,0x0)/HD(1,MBR,0xBE1AFDFA,0x3F,0xFBFC1)/\net\Udp4Dxe.efi. 
None of Tcg2Protocol/CcMeasurementProtocol is installed. 
InstallProtocolInterface: 5B1B31A1-9562-11D2-8E3F-00A0C969723B 3E154040 
Loading driver at 0x0003E127000 EntryPoint=0x0003E12E5C5 Udp4Dxe.efi 
InstallProtocolInterface: BC62157E-3E33-4FEC-9920-2D3B36D750DF 3E154E98 
ProtectUefiImageCommon - 0x3E154040   - 0x000000003E127000 - 0x0000000000009840 
Failed to locate EFI_RNG_PROTOCOL: Not Found  
ASSERT_EFI_ERROR (Status = Not Found) 
ASSERT [Udp4Dxe] /home/uefi/edk2/NetworkPkg/Library/DxeNetLib/DxeNetLib.c(938): !(((RETURN_STATUS)(Status)) >= 0x8000000000000000ULL)

But when I use the EDK2 Emulator to run UEFI, I can still load these drivers normally.

Do you have a driver that provides the EFI_RNG_PROTOCOL on your test system?

I think so. EDK2 provides the implementation of EFI_RNG_PROTOCOL in ./SecurityPkg/RandomNumberGenerator/RngDxe/RngDxe.c.

I tried to add the RngDex.inf  in OvmfPkgX64.dsc, but it still doesn't work

I have resolved this bug. When I compared EmulatorPkg.dsc (which does not report EFI_RNG-PROTOCOL Not Found) with OvmfPkgX64.dsc, I found that they used different LibraryClasses for Rng.
OvmfPkgX64.dsc use !include OvmfPkg/Include/Dsc/OvmfRngComponents.dsc.inc to specify the required LibraryClasses. The content in the file is as follows：
SecurityPkg/RandomNumberGenerator/RngDxe/RngDxe.inf {
  <LibraryClasses>
    RngLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseRngLib/BaseRngLib.inf
}

This is the highest priority method for specifying LibraryClasses in UEFI, so it covers other libraries to provide implementation of Rng. BaseRngLib uses CPU RNG instructions to provide random numbers (file comments below), but I am running the ovmf firmware on qemu.
## @file
#  Instance of RNG (Random Number Generator) Library.
#
#  BaseRng Library that uses CPU RNG instructions (e.g. RdRand) to
#  provide random numbers.
#
#  Copyright (c) 2023, Arm Limited. All rights reserved.<BR>
#  Copyright (c) 2021, NUVIA Inc. All rights reserved.<BR>
#  Copyright (c) 2015, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.<BR>
#
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-2-Clause-Patent
#
##

So when I commented out this library, the Rng service can run normally.
